# Data in input excel sheet is automatically showing in output excel sheet

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

See my code below:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("E://Pincodes Task//Pincodes-List.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sh=wb.getSheetAt(0);
int totalNoOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum();     
for(int i = 1; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {
    XSSFRow row=sh.getRow(i);
    pincode=new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));
    fis.close();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPincodeSearch"))
        .sendKeys(pincode);
    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnPincodeSearch")).click();              
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblNoResult']")).isDisplayed()) {
    String noData="No data for "+pincode+" code";
    XSSFSheet sh2=wb.getSheetAt(0);         
    XSSFRow row2=sh2.createRow(i);
    row2.createCell(0).setCellValue(noData);
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("E://Pincodes Task//Output-List.xlsx");
    wb.write(fos);
    fos.close();
} else {
    if(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdPincode_ctl02_HyperLink1")).isEnabled()) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdPincode_ctl02_HyperLink1")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        data=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TableCell4']")).getText();
        XSSFSheet sh2=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row2=sh2.createRow(i);
        row2.createCell(0).setCellValue(data);
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("E://Pincodes Task//Output-List.xlsx");
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

I need to read input from one Excel sheet and I need to save data taking from website in another Excel file, but input data is automatically saving in output file.

Comment: You need to get separate XSSFWorkbook instance for output xlsx, you are using same instance for input and output xlsx

Comment: Thanq @vvtx for your reply, I created separate Workbook instance like this  
 XSSFWorkbook wb2= null; but i am getting exception as-                   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PostalDetails.main(PostalDetails.java:49)

Comment: code reformatting, uppercases

Comment: Hi @Massimiliano, where can i use uppercase?

Comment: @Krishna my comment came out automatically since I modified your post not directly but through the Review Queue, that is a part of StackOverflow. I corrected some words that must be written uppercase, and that's all.

Comment: Oh Ok, Thank you @Massimiliano

Answer (score 0):

Find below code for reading and writing data. if required please refer the link 
[http://www.seleniumeasy.com/jxl-tutorials/set-data-into-excelsheet-with-jxl]

```
public static  WritableSheet readExcel()
{
    try 
    {
        //reading the excel file
        wbook = XSSFWorkbook.getWorkbook(new File("path\\testSampleData.xls"));
        wwbCopy = XSSFWorkbook.createWorkbook(new File("path\\testSampleDataCopy.xls"), wbook);
        WritableSheet shSheet = wwbCopy.getSheet(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        new CustomizedException(e, driver);
    }
    return shSheet;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ravi, I am getting this error    -                                                           The method createWorkbook(File, XSSFWorkbook) is undefined for the type XSSFWorkbook

Comment: direct you can mention file name in workbook instead in fis

Comment: I think is it for copying data from one excel file to another excel file?